# MVC how to submit value from dropdown list

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to create model that gets id from list of other models

please follow my steps It will be explained better but before you do, my goal is to make relationship between the model I create to an existing 1, so maybe my all way is wrong.

this is the 2 models relationship
ClientId<->ClientId
[image]

My steps were :

Step 1: I've created this view model

```
 public class SubscriptionViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Client")]
    public int clientId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Domain")]
    public string clientDomain { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Time")]
    public int subscriptionTime { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Document Access Key")]
    public string documentAccKey { get; set; }

}
```

Step 2: in my controller I took the client list and put it in viewdata

My [GET] create Action

```
 public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewData["clientList"] = DbHandlers.GetClientsList();
        return View();
    }
```

[image]

Step 3: created dropdown list from viewdata

My view:

```html
@model AccessibilityServiceControlPabel.Models.SubscriptionViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>SubscriptionViewModel</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.clientId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
               @Html.DropDownList("SelectedEmployee",new SelectList((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["clientList"], "ClientId", "ClientName"), "--Select--", new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.clientDomain, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.clientDomain, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.clientDomain, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.subscriptionTime, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.subscriptionTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.subscriptionTime, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.documentAccKey, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.documentAccKey, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.documentAccKey, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

And it looks fine on my view

[image]

Now for my problem:
After submitting the view, I don't get the selected value clientId.

My [HttpPost] create Action (still not complete)

```
 public ActionResult Create(SubscriptionViewModel subscriptionviewmodel)
    {
        var subscription = new Subscriptions();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

subscriptionviewmodel data does not contain the clientId data

this is the data I've insert in my view

[image]

After Submitting, this is what I get
[image]

As you can see the cientId is 0 and it was supposed to be 1 according to my selection.
Can someone please help me figure where I went wrong?

Could it be that my way is wrong by tring to get the clientId and what I really need is to send the all Client model.
I'm remiding that my main goal is to make relationship between them.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `Name` of your dropdown to the `model` name, In your case change the name from **SelectedEmployee** to **clientId**.

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.clientId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
               @Html.DropDownList("clientId",new SelectList((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["clientList"], "ClientId", "ClientName"), "--Select--", new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you are not passing the field to return in DropDownList(fistparameter,...). Thats why it is not returning the value back to form during form post. Change the first parameter of DropDownList("SelectEmployee",..) to your model property name.

```
 @Html.DropDownList("clientId",new SelectList((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["clientList"]....)
```